# Which method is faster? Condition IF or a math formula?

Tags: javascript, math, optimization, conditional-statements

It just switches the name & gender of the person by its previous gender.

```
function changeName(gender){
    if(gender==0){
        name='Foo';
        gender=1;
}else{
        name='Bar';
        gender=0;
    }
}
```

OR

```
names=['Foo','Bar'];
function changeName(gender){
    name=names[gender];
    gender=1-gender; // Thanks Kerrek
}
```

Comment: Ugh, why not `1 - gender`?

Comment: Why don't you try it out by yourself usig Firebug profiler?

Comment: The question as it stands is utterly academic, but there are two things to weigh against one another: One the one hand, unconditional code is better to branching code; on the other hand, the lookup may be implemented in a rather elaborate and expensive way. In C this question would have an easy answer; in JavaScript, you'll just have to profile.

Comment: I would suggest a complete rewrite then use jsPerf to test the speed difference.  You aren't changing gender/name, you're selecting (there may not be a change).  Change (i.e., toggle) would not need any parameters.  Also, these functions do not return or act on a name/gender object, they modify global scope which is just bad.

Comment: Yeah Kerrek, actualy i dind't realized your formula, it's really better, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/), a GREAT online tool which "aims to provide an easy way to create and share test cases, comparing the performance of different JavaScript snippets by running benchmarks."

Hope this helps, don't forget to post your results ;-)

Comment: added also my own (check out the difference to your FireFox), if this helped please mark as Answer for the other members, 10x

Comment: @BernaMariano - I'd say it's about time to change your browser ;-)

Comment: @Leon Sorry, I'm really confused, change my browser? And also i don't know what happened, because when I tested [your](http://jsperf.com/gender) code, the ChangeName1() was fastest, but I clicked test again, now the ChangeName2() was the fastest.. sorry for my newbieness? :laughs:

Answer (score 0):

If gender can only take on two values then there won't be a big different in performance. But if gender can have lot of values your if block will look something like this

```
if ( gender == 0 )
{
}
else if ( gender == 1 )
{
}
else if ( gender == 2 )
{
}
else if ( gender == 3 )
{
}
```

which will be slower and less pleasing to look at.

Comment: Gender having a lot of values? I can think of two, maybe 3 at a push

Comment: @DaveRlz: depends, are we talking about gender of nouns in a language?  There are languages that have 10 or more "genders" (i.e. classes of nouns which decline differently).

Comment: Even with people, there's at least 3 -- male, female, and "other".  And the "other" could mean a bunch of things.  Depending on the app and its audience, they might even be worthy of their own value.  Frankly, using a boolean'ish value seems quite short-sighted.